# Running a testcomplete script from an external application

Tags: excel, vbscript, testcomplete, vba

I am trying to run a testcomplete project and the script routines within it.
i used the following code:

```
Dim pn As String, un As String, rn As String
'Set ProjectSuiteName = "C:\Users\s.amin\Documents\TestComplete 10 Projects\DigiStyle1\DigiStyle1.pjs"
 pn = "DigiStyle_App"
 un = "login_test1"
 rn = "loginApp"
' Creates the application object
Set TestCompleteApp = CreateObject("TestComplete.TestCompleteApplication")
' Obtains the integration object
Set IntegrationObject = TestCompleteApp.Integration
' Opens the project suite
IntegrationObject.OpenProjectSuite ("C:\Users\s.amin\Documents\TestComplete 10 Projects\DigiStyle1\DigiStyle1.pjs")
' Runs the routine
   IntegrationObject.RunRoutine(pn, un, rn)
```

But i am getting the syntax error in the last statement. used this code from smartbear site itself.

Comment: i am coding this in the excel macro file within its vba editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a procedure with parameters, you need to either use the [`Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251710.aspx) keyword:

```
Call IntegrationObject.RunRoutine(pn, un, rn)
```

or drop the parentheses:

```
IntegrationObject.RunRoutine pn, un, rn
```